# browser sends non existant cookies

Tags: angular, google-chrome, firefox, cookies, amazon-cloudfront

In my Request Headers, I spotted in the cookie section:

`cookies: Session: Token-ABC; AnotherCookie: Value-XYZ;`

These cookies are NOT existing in my cookie jar.

When I perform an action which triggers a `Set-Cookie` action, such as `Log In`, I have the corresponding cookies set in my cookie jar.

Afterwards, when I send a request, I actually send the same TYPE of cookie, TWO times:

`cookies: Session: Token-ABC; AnotherCookie: Value-XYZ; Session: Token-DEF; AnotherCookie: Value-UVW;`

This severely interferes with the dependant mechanism.

I tried clearing the browser cache and restarting it. No go.

The Site is served using the AWS CloudFront service. I also tried to mess with the `Object Caching` settings, switched it to `customize` and made sure `Cookie Forwarding` is set to `None`.

This also occures to me in `FireFox`, as I was testing things using that browser too.

I tried `Opera` too, only when my testings were done and my newly created cookies were well received and stored. Therefore `Opera` remained "fresh" and did not cache any cookie values, and the dependant mechanisms worked as expected (no dups sent)

Anyone familiar with this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved

I copied the "non existant" cookies to my cookie jar by hand
Then, once logged in, I logged out and the `Set-Cookie: Session=''` header removed the invisible duplicate. Afterwards, removed the cookies in my cookie jar. Browser then was clear and nothing is duplicated now.